# Why does Angular let you inject the $provide service into config blocks?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, app-config, angularjs-injector

As per Angular documentation, we can only inject Providers (not instances) in config blocks.
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#module-loading-dependencies

But contrary to this Angular lets you inject `$provide` or `$inject` in spite of them being singleton service instances.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide

Comment: Read up on what a provider is then: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers (Service, Factory, Provider and more). (Also, all services in angular are singleton instances).

Comment: @ippi, I think the person who asked the question has gone through the documentations. So, if can NOT answer, please do NOT demotivate people. #StayAway

Answer (score 1):

This got me curious so I did some research. Here is what I found:

1. $injector cannot be injected into config blocks
2. $provide can be injected into config blocks

In code, the reason for 2 is that `$provide` is put into the `providerCache` before the `providerInjector` (the injector used in config blocks) is created. This ensures that it will always be a known provider to the `providerInjector`. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/auto/injector.js#L671

That said, I do agree that being able inject `$provide` into config blocks seems to contradict the general rule regarding what can be injected into configuration blocks stated here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#module-loading-dependencies

Even though it is clearly demonstrated to be something you can do here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#configuration-blocks

`$provide` might just be the one exception to the general rule.